# Is it possible to have a custom setter for mutableStateOf() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to do some operations two seconds after every time a certain state is set.

*Code inside viewModel:*

```
var isLoading = mutableStateOf(LoadingState.NONE)
    set(value) {
        Timber.d("Custom Setter") //Not Firing

        //Do something when the state is set to success.
        if(value.value == LoadingState.SUCCESS){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                delay(2000L)
                dispatchEvent(//some event)
            }
        }
        field = value
    }
```

The set{} block is not running at all. But the value is being correctly set.

When using delegation with the `by` keyword,

`Delegated property cannot have accessors with non-default implementations`

Is there a way to make custom setter work for mutableStateOf() in Jetpack Compose?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [snapshotFlow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#snapshotFlow(kotlin.Function0)) for this usecase. It creates a `Flow` from a given compose `State`.

```kotlin
var isLoading by mutableStateOf(LoadingState.NONE)
    private set

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        snapshotFlow { isLoading }
            .collect { 
                if(it == LoadingState.SUCCESS) {
                    delay(2000L)
                    dispatchEvent(//some event)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we can use scope functions to place the init block inside the variable scope. I made a separate answer for it. See below.

Comment: Yeah, probably you can do that too. But I find this approach using `init` a bit cleaner.

Comment: Is there a way to not update the value if a condition is not met? For example `if(isLoading > 0)` only then update the `isLoading` value. With your current example, it only reacts to a change, but you can't really customize your setter. I would appreciate an update on this answer.

Comment: Are you changing `isLoading` value at multiple places? If not, you can place this condition there only when you change its value.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ArpitShukla 's answer. We can also use scope functions to make the code block encapsulated.

```
var isLoading by mutableStateOf(LoadingState.NONE).also{ state ->
        viewModelScope.launch {
            snapshotFlow { state.value }
                .collect {
                    if(it == LoadingState.SUCCESS) {
                        delay(2000L)
                        dispatchEvent(//Fire event)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```