# Custom Setter for mutableStateOf() / MutableState in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to override the setter for the underlying value of a `MutableState`

Basically I want to achieve the exact behaviour of a non MutableState

```kotlin
object MyClass2 {
  val myProperty2: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            if (value>= 0) {
                field = value
            }
        }
}
```

Using `myProperty2 = -3` will execute my custom setter and not update the value since the `if` condition is not met.

```kotlin
object MyClass1 {
  val myProperty1: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(0)
        set(value) {
            if (value.value >= 0) {
                field = value
            }
        }
}
```

Using `myProperty1.value = -3` will ***NOT*** execute my custom setter since im changing the **underlying** value and not the `MutableState` itself

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541671/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-setter-for-mutablestateof-in-kotlin) but the answers look for state changes only.(updates the value automatically). I want to change the state only if a condition is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as our code is based on interfaces, we can always use composition and delegation to solve this kind of problems. In this case we can create our own implementation of `MutableState` and then implement everything according to our needs, possibly delegating to the original mutable state wherever it makes sense:

```kotlin
val myProperty1 = run {
    val state = mutableStateOf(0)
    object : MutableState<Int> by state {
        override var value: Int
            get() = state.value
            set(value) {
                if (value > 0) {
                    state.value = value
                }
            }
    }
}
```